# Question about right triangle and sin(2theta)

Tags: trigonometry

This is a pretty basic question but I just wanted clarification. I know that sin(theta) is opposite/hypotenuse regarding right triangles. But what would sin(2theta) be? would it be (opposite/hypotenuse) * 2? My problem here is my sin(theta) is x/3. But would sin(2theta) be (2x/3)?

Comment: Thats a very good guess! but no, $\sin x$ is not multiplicative : $$\sin(2x) \ne  2\sin (x)$$  See double angle identities http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number $\sin(2\theta)$ is the sine of twice the angle $\theta$. It is *almost never* equal to $2\sin(\theta)$.

But there is an important "double-angle" identity 
$$\sin(2\theta)=2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\tag{1}$$
 that you can use in your problem. If you know that $\sin(\theta)=\frac{x}{3}$, all you need to do to find $\sin(2\theta)$ is to find $\cos(\theta)$ and then use the Identity (1).

Answer (score 0):

$\sin 2\theta \not=2\sin \theta$, However 4\sin 2\theta  = 2\sin \theta \cos \theta$

As we know, $\cos2\theta \not= 2\cos \theta$, $$\cos2\theta=\sin^2 \theta-\cos^2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1=1-2\sin^2\theta.$$