# Finding $\theta$ given that $\sin(2\theta) = 0.99810$

Tags: trigonometry

**Question:** If $\sin(2\theta) = 0.99810$ then what is $\theta$?

**My try:** Can I just do inverse $\sin()$ of $2\theta$ then divide by $2$ to get $\theta$?

$\sin^{-1}(2\theta)=0.99810$

$2\theta= 86.47^\circ$

$\theta=86.47^\circ/2=43.23^\circ$?

Comment: That's valid but may be another theta giving another solution. inverse sine doesn't give all solutions.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  You correctly found a solution.  There may be others, depending on the domain.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @coffeemath    in the following post:
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/953494/question-about-right-triangle-and-sin2theta

members are saying that: The number sin(2θ) is the sine of twice the angle θ. It is almost never equal to 2sin(θ).

Comment: @technotux I looked at that but this question only is attempting to find theta given the value of sin(2 theta). That is not at all saying that sin(2theta) is 2sin(theta). Note that the OP first uses inverse sine to get a value for 2theta, and then divides the obtained value by 2. That surely gives theta.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $$\sin(x) = a, \ \ -1\le a\le1$$then we have $$x = 2k\pi + \sin^{-1}(a), \ \ \ k\in\mathbb{Z}$$ and $$x = 2k\pi + \pi -\sin^{-1}(a), \ \ \ k\in\mathbb{Z}$$Note that by definition, $\sin^{-1}(x)$ always returns a real number in the range $-\frac{\pi}{2}\le y \le \frac{\pi}{2}$. This restriction comes from the fact that we want $\sin^{-1}(x)$ be a single-valued function. I think the following plot is useful because using the same procedure (i.e. plotting the function and $y=c$) , we can solve other equations like $$\cos(x) = a,\ \ -1\le a\le1$$ and $$\tan(x) = a, \ \ \ a \in \mathbb{R}$$ in the general form.[image]
In this case, $\sin^{-1}(0.9981) \approx 1.50914$ and so the general solution is $$2\theta = 2k\pi + 1.50914$$ and $$2\theta = 2k\pi + \pi - 1.50914$$ This gives $$\theta = k\pi + 0.75457$$ and $$\theta = k\pi + \frac{\pi}{2} - 0.75457$$

Comment: so what is Theta?

Comment: @technotux I gave you the general formula. All you have to do is putting the numbers. Please read again.

Comment: @technotux I've added the final answer.

Comment: What is the value of k?

Comment: @technotux It can be any integer. There are infinitely many solutions to the problem because of the periodicity of $\sin$ function.